# How to Mock Integer.parseInt("Some String") using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

Can you please help me on mocking below line of code

```
Integer.parseInt("12345");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Don't*. There is absolutely no need to mock that. There is no circumstance in which invoking that method will do anything different. Just invoke the real method. (Also: that line of code has no side effect, so there is no reason to invoke it anyway).

Comment: If you need to test different values coming out of that call, you'll need to pass different `String` parameters in.  Mockito isn't designed to be able to change the behaviour of the JDK classes.

Comment: Why do you need to? Parsing integer is part of your unit. Unless you somehow want to drop the dependency on the JDK, whatever that even means. So again, why would you want to do that?